# Android Alarm Notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I am trying to implement a Alarm functionality in my  mobile apps. Below is my use case

1. User can set reminder from Activity **"A"** once the reminder is set, User will receive a notification 10min before the set time. Now user can remove the reminder from another activity , which is let suppose **"B"**.
2. Apart from that I also want that user can reschedule his/her reminder setting from notification window.

Below is the code I have written for use case 1

```
private void setAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, RepeatAlarm.class);

    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(A.this,
        0, new Intent(A.this, RepeatAlarm.class), 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        firstTime, 30*1000, mAlarmSender);

        // Tell the user about what we did.
        Toast.makeText(A.this, R.string.repeating_scheduled,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void stopAlarm(){

    // And cancel the alarm.
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(mAlarmSender);

        // Tell the user about what we did.
        Toast.makeText(B.this, R.string.repeating_unscheduled,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

==============

```
public class RepeatAlarm extends Service {
    NotificationManager mNM;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        showNotification();

        Thread thr = new Thread(null, mTask, "RepeatAlarm");
        thr.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        mNM.cancel(R.string.alarm_service_started);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.alarm_service_finished, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * The function that runs in our worker thread
     */
    Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 15*1000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                synchronized (mBinder) {
                    try {
                        mBinder.wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }


            RepeatAlarm.this.stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void showNotification() {

        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.alarm_service_started);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text,
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, B.class), 0);

        // Set default sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        //Set the default Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // Set the light pattern
        notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        notification.ledOnMS = 300;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;


        //Custom notification view
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Notification");
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        // Send the notification.
        // We use a layout id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
        mNM.notify(R.string.alarm_service_started, notification);
    }

    /**
     * This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See RemoteService
     * for a more complete example.
     */
    private final IBinder mBinder = new Binder(){
        @Override
        protected boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply,
                int flags) throws RemoteException {
                return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
            }
    };
}
```

Now I am trying to attempt the 2nd case, for that I put 2 buttons on the notification layout, called Reschedule and Cancel, but in this case my view is not showing in the notification window, I have googled from last 2 days but no-luck, Now it is very alarming situation for me, I have to complete it any way by end of the day. So any suggestion or workaround will extremely helpful for me.

Thanks

Ashish

Comment: have you tried anything besides the code you posted? Have you run your code in the debugger? Is your showNotification() method being called? Have tried to display a simple notification?